# Access DOM in Electron BrowserView

Tags: javascript, dom, electron

How do you access the DOM of content loaded into a `BrowserView`?

I have a `BrowserWindow` and `BrowserView` defined like this (defined simply until I get it working):

```
let win = null
let view = null

// Create the window  
win = new BrowserWindow({
 height: 600,
 width: 800
})

// HTML file to load into window
win.loadFile('main.html')

// Create main browserView
view = new BrowserView()

// Set BrowserView bounds (usually in a function to handle window resize)
wb = win.getBounds()
view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: wb.width, height: wb.height })

// Set BrowserView in window
win.setBrowserView(view)

// Load url in BrowserView
view.webContents.loadURL(url)
```

main.html is boiler-plate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

renderer.js is as well:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
const $ = require('jquery')
```

I can send input to the view like this (main.js):

```
view.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'keyDown', keyCode: 'space'})
```

I can listen for generic events in the view like this (main.js):

```
view.webContents.on('media-started-playing', () => {
 console.log('Playing')
})
```

But how do I access the DOM of the loaded URL in the `BrowserView`?
I can find chapter and verse on the `<webview>` but that is a different animal.
I found a question around renderer process differences between the `BrowserView` and `<webview>` that mentions that the `BrowserView` uses the same renderer process as the `BrowserWindow` but that doesn't make any sense to me as how would the `BrowserView` content know if there is no reference to it? For kicks I tried to change the background-color on a known div ID using an IPC channel from main to the renderer when the `BrowserView` content is finished loading and nothing happened. Even tied it to a button and nada which, again, is not surprising.

I feel like this must be a forrest for the trees scenario.
I'm using Electron 11.

Comment: can you send DOM elements via ipc to your main process (though this may very well not work)? Otherwise, I'm not sure how you can do this (the DOM elements are in a separate process) without doing some kind of `webContents.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById(...)")` or something

Comment: Thanks, that does work (though I used `view.webContents.executeJavaScript`) I was just hoping there was a way to do it without having to send javascript over as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to get this information via `view.webContents.executeJavaScript("document.getElementById(...)")`.

The page is loaded in a separate renderer process, so you can't really just access that information from your main process, except via the executeJavaScript` API.

If you have control over the page, you could send down the appropriate information via IPC, though you won't be able to send down the the entire DOM Element over since it won't be serialized correctly as per [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm):

> Cloning DOM nodes likewise throws a `DATA_CLONE_ERR` exception.