# Can Electron read DOM from BrowserView?

Tags: javascript, electron

is it possible to read DOM of website with given url in BrowserView?
I have code that looks like this one, and Electron is throwing an error:
"An object could not be cloned"

````
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 800,
    width: 1200,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
    },
  });

  const view = new BrowserView({
    webPreferences: {
      webSecurity: false,
      allowRunningInsecureContent: true,
    },
  });

  mainWindow.setBrowserView(view);
  view.setBounds({ x: 200, y: 0, width: 900, height: 800 });
  view.webContents.loadURL("https://electronjs.org");
  view.setAutoResize({ width: true, height: true });
  view.webContents
    .executeJavaScript("document.querySelector('body')")
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("html", result);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access DOM in Electron BrowserView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65511624/access-dom-in-electron-browserview)

Comment: basically, no you can't send down the entire DOM element back